# Presence of a distinct number line in a lattice square

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

Fill the $n\times n$ lattice square with natural numbers $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ each of which is used $n$ times. Define column $j$ for a given $j$ as $(a_{i,j}), i=1,2,\cdots,n$; row $i$ for a given $j$ as $(a_{i,j}), j=1,2,\cdots,n$; positive diagonal $k$ for a given $k\ge0$ as $(a_{i,j}), j-i\equiv k(\mod n), k=0,1,2,\cdots,n-1$; negative diagonal $k$ for a given $k\le0$ as $(a_{i,j}), j+i\equiv k+2 (\mod n), k=0,1,2,\cdots,n-1$. Must there be a row, column or a diagonal (positive or negative) consists of all the distinct $n$ natural numbers?

Comment: No: there is a simple counterexample with $n=4$.

Comment: @GregMartin: Would you please share the counterexample? Are you able to prove the claim for $n=3$?

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You need to [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for your question. Otherwise it just looks like you want somebody to do your homework for you; that's not what this site is for. If you add some appropriate context, we will be happy to help.

Comment: @GregMartin: I appreciate that you keep a vigilant eye. However, this is not a homework. I am not taking any coursework. This is my conjecture formed after I trying many examples in $n=3$. The trying is in the very formation of the conjecture. I edited the question to include more diagonals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that there are only $4n$ straight lines, and each straight line can be "blocked" by placing two copies of the same number on it; in principle that means we need only $8n$ numbers (out of the $n^2$ at our disposal) to force a counterexample. To me this suggests that the conjecture is likely to be false for all but the smallest $n$.

With this idea, it's easy to come up with a counterexample for $n=6$, and only a little harder to come up with counterexamples for $n=5$ and $n=4$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&2&2&2 \\ 1&1&1&2&2&2 \\ 3&3&3&4&4&4 \\ 3&3&3&4&4&4 \\ 5&5&5&6&6&6 \\ 5&5&5&6&6&6
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&2&2&2 \\ 1&1&2&2&5 \\ 1&3&3&4&4 \\ 3&3&3&4&4 \\ 5&5&5&5&4
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&4&4 \\ 1&1&2&2 \\ 3&3&2&2 \\ 3&3&4&4
\end{pmatrix}
$$

(One can show by brute force that there is no counterexample for $n=3$, even if only the main diagonals are considered.)

Comment: Nice. Is there a more elegant way to prove the conjecture for $n=3$ than brute force enumeration?

Comment: For any given placement of the three 1s (there are only a few due to symmetries), note that in a hypothetical counterexample, any straight line with a single one must have the other two entries the same; use this fact a few times with different lines to show that 2 or 3 must appear at least four times, a contradiction.